# Is it possible to add click function that would pop up audio files for my code?

Tags: jquery

I have written code with mouseover to display gifs over an image. Is it possible to add a mouse enter so that audio files will be displayed when I click on the image.

I am new to jQuery and lost at the moment.

```
<img src="images/chi.png" onmouseover="this.src='gifimage/ち.gif'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/chi.png'"/> 
<img src="images/e.png" onmouseover="this.src='gifimage/ら.gif'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/e.png'"/> 
<img src="images/fu_hu.png" onmouseover="this.src='gifimage/ふ.gif'"
         onmouseout="this.src='images/fu_hu.png'"/>
```

Comment: Audio files... *"displayed?"* ...please elaborate.

Comment: I think I have started the code incorrectly. I have multiple symbols on my page and want each symbol to display a gif drawing of the symbol and then an audio pronunciation of the symbol. I would like to hover over the symbol and have the gif drawing and then click on the symbol to pop up an audio

Comment: That's feasible but we'll need you to post the jQuery as well (working or not). Although not required, I could post a functioning example if you could provide absolute paths to some images and mp3 files to save time.

Answer (score 0):

I would use sme [data- attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the second image source and the sound to play.

Then using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can define the handlers for every events. And this is a much clearer way than inline `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` handlers which you have to repeat the same code everywhere...

I suggest you to use one single class for all those images having the same behavior. See the example below.

```js
$(".someClass").on({
  
  "mouseenter": function(){
    // Save the original src in a data attribute
    $(this).data("original_src",$(this).attr("src"));
    // change the src with the second src
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).data("alt_src"));
  },
  
  "mouseleave": function(){
    // Restore the original src
    $(this).attr("src",$(this).data("original_src"));
  },
  
  "click": function(){
    // Play the sound
    var sound = $("<audio>").attr("src",$(this).data("sound"));
    sound[0].play();
  }
});
```

```css
.someClass{
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="someClass"
     title="Click to play the sound"
     src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/17/10/03/old-phone-2650639_960_720.png"
     data-alt_src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/03/10/42/phone-311185_960_720.png"
     data-sound="https://freesound.org/data/previews/344/344365_6201031-lq.mp3">
```